# How can i access image of note model on template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Hope You Are Good

I Have A Problem i uploaded multiple images from these models

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Images(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,null=True,blank=True)
```

now my question is how can i access images of note in jinja template

because this doesn't work

```
<p><span>{{ note.image }}</span></p>
```

my question is how can i get images of note model

in html template

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the *reverse manager* as

```
{% for image in note.images_set.all %}
    {{ image.image }}
{% endfor %}
```